# Can't connect to my Windows 10 File Sharing Server

Tags: networking, windows-10, file-sharing

My Windows 10 computer has been configured to discover devices on the network and enable file sharing. This however is just not working whatever I try to do. I tried resetting the network adapter, resetting all network settings + driver, disable and enable the file sharing, starting and stopping services. Nothing worked and I still am not able to connect to my computer from other devices on the network. The computer can't even connect to `\\\127.0.0.1` or `\\\localhost`. It just keeps saying `The network path was not found` and `The remote device or resource won't accept the connection`.

[image: The network path was not found]
[image: The remote device or resource won't accept the connection]

EDIT: Possible problem: I'm using Windows 10 Home and this may be the reason that other versions of windows cannot connect to my smb server. Also I have detected that PsExec doesn't work because of the problem.

[image: doesn't work]

Comment: I think this question has been asked in the stackOveflow forum [Can't access 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543443/cant-access-127-0-0-1)

Comment: No, other computer can just access a server on my computer like a web server (127.0.0.1:80 also works fine). It's the actual \\ip (file sharing or smb) server that doesn't work, but is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.
The Wired Autoconfig Service was disabled and was never running. After enabling it everything was working just fine. I don't know how it could've been disabled and that it was causing this problem but it got fixed and that's what matters.